# Undefined reference to... when linking library header

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I'm trying to compile a C program that uses `libvncserver` but no matter what I do I keep getting `undefined reference` errors, the library I'm having troubles with is `rfb/rfb.h`.

## vnc.c code (copied from [here](http://libvnc.github.io/doc/html/camera_8c-example.html)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <rfb/rfb.h>
#define WIDTH 640
#define HEIGHT 480
#define BPP 4
/* 15 frames per second (if we can) */
#define PICTURE_TIMEOUT (1.0/15.0)
/*
* throttle camera updates
*/
int TimeToTakePicture() {
static struct timeval now={0,0}, then={0,0};
double elapsed, dnow, dthen;
gettimeofday(&now,NULL);
dnow = now.tv_sec + (now.tv_usec /1000000.0);
dthen = then.tv_sec + (then.tv_usec/1000000.0);
elapsed = dnow - dthen;
if (elapsed > PICTURE_TIMEOUT)
memcpy((char *)&then, (char *)&now, sizeof(struct timeval));
return elapsed > PICTURE_TIMEOUT;
}
/*
* simulate grabbing a picture from some device
*/
int TakePicture(unsigned char *buffer)
{
static int last_line=0, fps=0, fcount=0;
int line=0;
int i,j;
struct timeval now;
/*
* simulate grabbing data from a device by updating the entire framebuffer
*/
for(j=0;j<HEIGHT;++j) {
for(i=0;i<WIDTH;++i) {
buffer[(j*WIDTH+i)*BPP+0]=(i+j)*128/(WIDTH+HEIGHT); /* red */
buffer[(j*WIDTH+i)*BPP+1]=i*128/WIDTH; /* green */
buffer[(j*WIDTH+i)*BPP+2]=j*256/HEIGHT; /* blue */
}
buffer[j*WIDTH*BPP+0]=0xff;
buffer[j*WIDTH*BPP+1]=0xff;
buffer[j*WIDTH*BPP+2]=0xff;
}
/*
* simulate the passage of time
*
* draw a simple black line that moves down the screen. The faster the
* client, the more updates it will get, the smoother it will look!
*/
gettimeofday(&now,NULL);
line = now.tv_usec / (1000000/HEIGHT);
if (line>HEIGHT) line=HEIGHT-1;
memset(&buffer[(WIDTH * BPP) * line], 0, (WIDTH * BPP));
/* frames per second (informational only) */
fcount++;
if (last_line > line) {
fps = fcount;
fcount = 0;
}
last_line = line;
fprintf(stderr,"%03d/%03d Picture (%03d fps)\r", line, HEIGHT, fps);
/* success! We have a new picture! */
return (1==1);
}
/*
* Single-threaded application that interleaves client servicing with taking
* pictures from the camera. This way, we do not update the framebuffer
* while an encoding is working on it too (banding, and image artifacts).
*/
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
long usec;
rfbScreenInfoPtr server=rfbGetScreen(&argc,argv,WIDTH,HEIGHT,8,3,BPP);
if(!server)
return 0;
server->desktopName = "Live Video Feed Example";
server->frameBuffer=(char*)malloc(WIDTH*HEIGHT*BPP);
server->alwaysShared=(1==1);
/* Initialize the server */
rfbInitServer(server);
/* Loop, processing clients and taking pictures */
while (rfbIsActive(server)) {
if (TimeToTakePicture())
if (TakePicture((unsigned char *)server->frameBuffer))
rfbMarkRectAsModified(server,0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
usec = server->deferUpdateTime*1000;
rfbProcessEvents(server,usec);
}
return(0);
}
```

## Compiler output:

```
sudo gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -O2 vnc.c

/tmp/cc7dpMCs.o: In function `main':
/home/arcm/Projects/c/vnc.c:77: undefined reference to `rfbGetScreen'
/home/arcm/Projects/c/vnc.c:84: undefined reference to `rfbInitServerWithPthreadsAndZRLE'
/home/arcm/Projects/c/vnc.c:91: undefined reference to `rfbProcessEvents'
/home/arcm/Projects/c/vnc.c:86: undefined reference to `rfbIsActive'
/home/arcm/Projects/c/vnc.c:89: undefined reference to `rfbMarkRectAsModified'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've got `libvncserver0` and `libvncserver-dev` installed and i'm using ubuntu 14.04.
I tried:

```
sudo gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -O2 vnc.c -lm
sudo gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -O2 vnc.c -ldl
sudo gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -O2 -ldl vnc.c
sudo gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -O2 -I/usr/include/rfb -L/usr/include/rbf/rfb.h vnc.c 
sudo gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -O2 -I/usr/include/rfb vnc.c
sudo gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -O2 -L/usr/include/rbf/rfb.h vnc.c
sudo gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -O2 /usr/include/rbf/rfb.h vnc.c
sudo gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -O2 -L/usr/include/rbf/rfb.h -ldl vnc.c
```

But I get the same errors everytime. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Instead of randomly trying different options why don't you read the manual and find out what the options mean?

Comment: Hi razzak. I've repaired this question, in particular relating to removing voting commentary. Since you have reverted I will downvote, and if you revert again I will flag for a moderator. "Please don't downvote" messages are not of interest to readers - if you want to comment on voting, add a comment (and in my opinion they can encourage more downvotes, so I think they are a waste of time).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't "link" a library header, you *include* it so the compiler sees the library's *declarations* at compile time and knows that `rfbGetScreen()` is a function that takes so-and-so many arguments of this-and-that type and returns a `rfbScreenInfoPtr`. *How* it does this (the *definition* of the function) is not important to the compiler. It just adds a *reference* to that function, which is left for the linker to resolve. (Note the vocabulary here.)

You *link* your compiled code to the library *binary*. This is done by the linker, in a different (and later) step that just *happens* to be supported by the same frontend as compiling your source (`gcc`). In this step, any of the library functions that your code actually *uses* (references) are *resolved* by linking them in from the specified libraries.

This here...

```
sudo gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -O2 vnc.c
```

...links only the standard library and runtime, as there are no specific linking instructions in there.

This here...

```
-L/usr/include/rbf/rfb.h
```

...is nonsense, as `-L` is for giving **directories** where library binaries should be looked for (and is not necessary if the library in question is installed in the standard location).

The actual link instruction is `-l`. If you state `-lfoo`, then the library `libfoo` is searched for any undefined references.

This here...

```
-ldl
```

...is linking `libdl`, and from that you should be able to deduce that...

```
-lvncserver
```

...is what you're looking for (assuming that `<rfb/rfb.h>` actually does refer to `libvncserver`, which I don't know).

Note that the linker is processing libraries in the sequence they are given on the command line, so you need to state `-lvncserver` *after* `vnc.c`, because only then does the linker know *which* undefined references it ought to be looking for in `libvncserver`.

**And never, *ever* run a compiler as `sudo`.** Why in {.....}'s name do you think this would be necessary?

Comment: Make sure you put `-lvncserver` after `vnc.c`, and just to repeat the important point: **never run a compiler with `sudo`**

Comment: I ran: `gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -O2 -lvncserver vnc.c` and got same undefined references errors!

Comment: @razzak: *Please* take a step back and familiarize yourself with the toolchain you're using. If linking to a library poses such an issue to you, you shouldn't try to wade deep waters like VNC programming. Besides, what Jonathan said: Link statements come *after* the source being compiled, because only then does the compiler know which symbols *need* to be linked.

Comment: @DevSolar thanks i ran this `gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -O2 -o vnc vnc.c -lvncserver` and worked :). should i always put link statements after source file?

Comment: @razzak: See updated answer. And *please* consider going through some more sandbox tutorials before tackling "real" code, because C has *lots* of things that will catch you unawares unless you did your homework first. It's very much *not* a trial-and-error language.

Comment: @DevSolar thanks for all your help, i'm still noob in c :) and i will try to be careful with my codings. thanks again.

Comment: @razzak: No problem, we've all started somewhere. ;-)